# How to select distinct Career_Name and only show once

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I'm trying to get output like this:

```
[Career_Name]                     [GroupName]
 Production Career Master          CNC Programmers
                                   Machinists
                                   Machine Operators
                                   Assemblers
                                   Production Helpers
```

I'm currently getting output like:

```
[Career_Name]                     [GroupName]
Production Career Master           CNC Programmers
Production Career Master           Machinists
Production Career Master           Machine Operators
Production Career Master           Assemblers
Production Career Master           Production Helpers
```

I'm running a query like this:

```
SELECT distinct(Career_Name), `GroupName`
FROM `DOR_Career_Master` DCM, `DOR_Pathway` DP, `DOR_Career_Group` DCG
WHERE
DCM.`DOR_Career_Master_ID`=DP.`DOR_Career_Master_ID`
AND
DCG.`DOR_Career_Group_ID`=DP.`DOR_Career_Group_ID`
```

Can someone help here?

Thank you

Comment: Not entering this as an answer, as mysql isn't my flavor and there might be something I'm missing because of that, but that said: I think your best option is to filter your output through an external script. I am not aware of a facility for this in sql itself.

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are using SQL incorrectly. You should do this kind of UI processing in the presentation layer...